# Can't run Cordova android app in Emulator (Ionic app)

Tags: android, cordova, android-emulator

I have created an android emulator but I am not able to get it work and run and android app with cordova. Using Mac.

When I run:

```
/avdmanager list avd
```

I get:

```
    Name: AVD16
  Device: wear_round_chin_320_290 (Google)
    Path: /var/root/.android/avd/AVD16.avd
  Target: Google APIs (Google Inc.)
          Based on: Android 4.1 (Jelly Bean) Tag/ABI: google_apis/x86
  Sdcard: 100M
```

So, my AVD emulator exists, but when I run in my project folder:

```
cordova emulate --target=AVD16 android
```

I get:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.54 secs
Built the following apk(s):
    /Users/francisco/{PROJECT_FOLDER}/platforms/android/build/outputs/apk/android-debug.apk
ANDROID_HOME=/Users/francisco/Library/Android/sdk
JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_25.jdk/Contents/Home
Waiting for emulator to start...
PANIC: Unknown AVD name [AVD16], use -list-avds to see valid list.
HOME is defined but there is no file AVD16.ini in $HOME/.android/avd
(Note: Directories are searched in the order $ANDROID_AVD_HOME, $ANDROID_SDK_HOME/avd, and $HOME/.android/avd)
```

And nothing happens, emulator is not opened, just gets stoped forever.

What could I do to run this app on that emulator?